# Showing button on jquery page load event is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am displaying button on jquery page load event but it is not working. After the page is rendered, it is not visible.

It works fine if i set the visibility in code behind Page Load event.

**Jquery**

```
function pageLoad() {
   $('#btnSwitchDistributor').css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'display': 'inline-block' });
}
```

**Html**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSwitchDistributor" runat="server" Text="Switch Distributor" Visible="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.visible), when you set `Visible="false"` in your server-side code then the element is not rendered to the client at all.  Which means your button isn't "invisble" on the resulting page, it *doesn't exist* on the resulting page.  No JavaScript code can interact with an element that isn't present.

It sounds like instead you want to apply a *style* to the control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSwitchDistributor" runat="server" Text="Switch Distributor" style="display:none;" />
```

**Aside from that**, there are two two potential issues here which I can't necessarily confirm from the content of the question, but which you'll want to check...

1. The `ID` value you're looking for is the server-side object's `ID`.  This *may not necessarily* be the client-side `id` of the resulting HTML element.  Examine the page source to see the client-side `id`.  If it's different then you may need to set it explicitly using [the `ClientID` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid).
2. Do you ever *call* `pageLoad()` in your JavaScript code?  If not then, well, you'd need to do that.  I assume in [the `document.ready` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)?  For jQuery that may be as simple as: `$(pageLoad)`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the visible html attribute and the JQuery css.